# Can't boot in Ubuntu (Dual boot with Windows 10)

Tags: dual-boot

I've had Ubuntu on my computer about 2 years ago and I have installed it as a second OS with Windows 8. After upgrading to Win 8.1 the boot menu has disappeared though all the allocated disk space is still there. Now I once again need Ubuntu (atm I have Win10) and I would like to know how is it possible to bring the boot menu back. And I would also like to know if it's possible to switch it on or off whenever I need it or not.

Comment: When you dual boot with Windows, Windows will delete the grub menu. So you need to use the Ubuntu installation disc and boot into it, then re-install grub

Comment: @ryekayo thank you. Is it possible to "disable" or enable grub whenever I want?

Comment: Well the grub is the bootloader for the OS...Im not sure if it works that way...

Comment: @Erop, you need not to enable/disable grub at all. When you would reinstall the grub this time it should automatically detect Windows installation and add an entry in Grub Menu so that on boot you would be given an option to boot into Ubuntu or Windows. Alternatively, you can add Ubuntu's entry into Windows' bootloader but I'm not sure Windows 8 would play nicely or not. Windows 7 did at least.